# Show that $g(x,y) = \sqrt{|x-y|}$ is equivalent with the usual Euclidean metric $d(x,y) = |x-y|$.

Tags: general-topology

> Show that $g(x,y) = \sqrt{|x-y|}$ is equivalent with the usual Euclidean metric $d(x,y) = |x-y|$.

I have that $g(x,y) = \sqrt{d(x,y)}$ and that $d(x,y) = (g(x,y))^2$. And I need to show that $\operatorname{id}: (\mathbb{R}, g) \to (\mathbb{R}, d)$ is homeomorhpic, but I can’t figure out how to find the explicit formula for the identity map. I know it’s $id(x) = x$, but I have this now with different metrics so how should I represent this?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to show $\text{id}$ is continuous both ways; it's clearly a bijection which is its own inverse.

So for forward continuity: $$\forall x \in \Bbb R: \forall \varepsilon >0: \exists \delta >0: \forall y \in \Bbb R: (g(x,y) < \delta) \to (|x-y| < \varepsilon)\tag{1}$$

Check that taking $\delta = \sqrt{\varepsilon}$ for any $x$ will do the job.

And for continuity of $\text{id}: (\Bbb R,d) \to (\Bbb R, g)$ we need:
$$\forall x \in \Bbb R: \forall \varepsilon >0: \exists \delta >0: \forall y \in \Bbb R: (|x-y| < \delta) \to (g(x,y) < \varepsilon)\tag{2}$$

where taking $\delta=\varepsilon^2$ for any $x$ will do.

Comment: I know this, but what is $id$? This feels weird since it’s from different metric spaces.

Comment: It's implicit because $\textrm{id}(x) = x$ so you don't see it that directly. In general for any function $f: (\Bbb R,g) \to (\Bbb R,d)$ we'd have $$\forall x \in \Bbb R: \forall \varepsilon >0: \exists \delta >0: \forall y \in \Bbb R: (g(x,y) < \delta) \to (|f(x)-f(y)| < \varepsilon)$$ and here $f(x)=x$ etc.